# How to create and use a custom IFormatProvider for DateTime?

Tags: c#, iformatprovider

I was trying to create an `IFormatProvider` implementation that would recognize custom format strings for DateTime objects. Here is my implementation:

```
 public class MyDateFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
 {
  public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
  {
   if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
   {
    return this;
   }
   return null;
  }

  public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
  {
   if(arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
   if (arg.GetType() != typeof(DateTime)) return arg.ToString();
   DateTime date = (DateTime)arg;
   switch(format)
   {
    case "mycustomformat":
     switch(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
     {
      case "en-GB":
       return date.ToString("ddd dd MMM");
      default:
       return date.ToString("ddd MMM dd");
     }
    default:
     throw new FormatException();
   }
  }
```

I was expecting to be able to use it in the `DateTime.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)` method like so, but :

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2000, 1, 2);
string s = d.ToString("mycustomformat", new MyDateFormatProvider());
```

In that example, running in the US Culture, the result is `"00cu0Ao00or0aA"`, apparently because the standard DateTime format strings are being interpreted.

However, when I use the same class in the following way:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2000, 1, 2);
string s = String.Format(new MyDateFormatProvider(), "{0:mycustomformat}", d);
```

I get what I expect, namely `"Sun Jan 02"`

I don't understand the different results. Could someone explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checking the `DateTime.ToString` method with Reflector shows that the `DateTime` structure uses the `DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance` method to get the provider to be used for formatting. The `DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance` requests a formatter of type `DateTimeFormatInfo` from the provider passed in, never for `ICustomFormmater`, so it only returns an instance of a `DateTimeFormatInfo` or `CultureInfo` if no provider is found. It seems that the `DateTime.ToString` method does not honor the `ICustomFormatter` interface like the `StringBuilder.Format` method does, as your `String.Format` example shows.

I agree that the `DateTime.ToString` method should support the `ICustomFormatter` interface, but it does not seem to currently. This may all have changed or will change in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I was thinking I was misunderstanding the interface and expected implementation, so it's good to know that it's the DateTime implementation that's wacky :-)

Answer (score 22):

The short explanation is that while

```
DateTime.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

lets you pass anything implementing `IFormatProvider` as one of its parameters, it actually only supports 2 possible types implementing `IFormatProvider` inside its code:

`DateTimeFormatInfo` or `CultureInfo`

If your parameter cannot be casted (using `as`) as either or those, the method will default to `CurrentCulture`.

`String.Format` is not limited by such bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Use extension method :)

```
public static class FormatProviderExtension
    {
        public static string FormatIt(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            if (arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
            if (arg.GetType() != typeof(DateTime)) return arg.ToString();
            DateTime date = (DateTime)arg;
            switch (format)
            {
                case "mycustomformat":
                    switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
                    {
                        case "en-GB":
                            return date.ToString("ddd dd MMM");
                        default:
                            return date.ToString("ddd MMM dd");
                    }
                default:
                    throw new FormatException();
            }
        }

        public static string ToString(this DateTime d, IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format)
        {
            return FormatIt(format, d, formatProvider);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, looks like extension methods are my only option here. Thanks for the reply!