# Format TimeSpan greater than 24 hour

Tags: c#, vb.net, formatting, timespan

Say I convert some seconds into the TimeSpan object like this:

```vb
Dim sec = 1254234568
Dim t As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec)
```

How do I format the TimeSpan object into a format like the following:

```
>105hr 56mn 47sec
```

Is there a built-in function or do I need to write a custom function?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Well, the simplest thing to do is to format this yourself, e.g.

```
return string.Format("{0}hr {1}mn {2}sec",
                     (int) span.TotalHours,
                     span.Minutes,
                     span.Seconds);
```

In VB:

```vb
Public Shared Function FormatTimeSpan(span As TimeSpan) As String
    Return String.Format("{0}hr {1}mn {2}sec", _
                         CInt(Math.Truncate(span.TotalHours)), _
                         span.Minutes, _
                         span.Seconds)
End Function
```

I don't know whether any of the `TimeSpan` formatting in .NET 4 would make this simpler.

Comment: You may want to give VB code, though, as the code in the question looks like it :-)

Comment: Am I missing something? I get nervous when my answer disagrees with Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: `((int) span.TotalMinutes) % 60` can be replaced by `span.Minutes`. The same thing with seconds.

Comment: Oops, yes, got carried away after the TotalHours - which *is* required.

Comment: HHow do I check if total hour > 1 then append "hrs" ortherwise, just append "hr" within the String.Format statement?

Comment: @Maxd: Well, you could add an extra format parameter which ended up as "s" or "" depending on whether TotalHours was greater than 1. I don't have time to provide sample code right now I'm afraid.

Comment: @Joh Skeet I think, when you cast TotalHours to Integer, by default the TotalHours is rounded up. So, 34526 sec will be 10hr 35mn 26sec, which is not correct. 34526 sec = 9hr 35mn 26sec. Math.Floor(t.TotalHours) will do the job.

Comment: @Angkor: Wrong.  Integral casts will truncate.

Comment: @SLaks, I did try the sample he wrote. 34526 sec = 10hr 35mn 26sec, which is NOT correct. Did you try it?

Comment: @Angkor: Fixed, thanks. Blech - as far as I can tell there's no simple "convert and truncate" operator in VB, the equivalent of casting in C#.

Comment: @Angkor: Sorry; I was thinking in C#.

Comment: Any particular reason for choosing `Math.Truncate` over `Math.Floor`? Also, `String.Format` did the right thing for me without the extra `CInt`. I assume this situation hasn't been remedied with `TimeSpan` formatting in 4.0?

Comment: @JeffBridgman: If the timespan is -30 minutes, you wouldn't want it to show as -1 hour, would you? Without the CInt, I'd have *expected* it to show as something like "1.0" rather than "1", but I suspect i didn't check it. I'm not sure what you mean by "I assume this situation hasn't been" - but yes, custom formatting in .NET 4 would indeed have made this simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I meant the there wasn't an awesome format string that would grab `TotalHours` instead of `Hours`. I think you still have to do something like "String.Format({0}hr {1:mm}mn {1:ss}sec", (int)t.TotalHours, t)` instead of `duration.ToString("xx:mm:ss")` where `xx` would have given me total hours.

Comment: @Jeff: ah, yes, for multiday values. Don't think so, although I could be wrong. Noda Time handles this better :)

Answer (score 15):

**Edit Oct 2018**: C# 6/VB 14 introduced [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) which may or may not be simpler than the first code segment of my **original answer**.  Thankfully, the syntax for interpolation is identical for both languages: a preceding `$`.

#### C# 6

```cs
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(105, 56, 47);
Console.WriteLine($"{(int)t.TotalHours}h {t:mm}mn {t:ss}sec");
```

#### Visual Basic 14

```vb
dim t As New TimeSpan(105, 56, 47)
Console.WriteLine($"{CInt(Math.Truncate(t.TotalHours))}h {t:mm}mn {t:ss}sec")
```

**Edit Nov 2021**: The above answer only works for positive `TimeSpan`s and negative ones less than or equal to `-1` hour.  If you have a negative `TimeSpan` in the range `(-1, 0]hr`, you'll need to manually insert the negative yourself.  Note, this is also true of the original answer.

```c#
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-30 * 60 - 10); // -(30mn 10 sec)
Console.WriteLine($"{(ts.Ticks < 0 && (int)ts.TotalHours == 0 ? "-" : "")}{(int)t.TotalHours}h {t:mm}mn {t:ss}sec");
```

Since this is cumbersome, I recommend creating a helper function.

```c#
string Neg(TimeSpan ts)
{
  return ts.Ticks < 0 && (int)ts.TotalHours == 0 ? "-" : "";
}

TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-30 * 60 - 10); // -(30mn 10 sec)
Console.WriteLine($"{Neg(ts)}{(int)t.TotalHours}h {t:mm}mn {t:ss}sec");
```

I don't know VB well enough to write the equivalent version.

See a quick example of C# [here](https://code.labstack.com/JkNzBy-3) including the [`ValueTuple`s](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) feature introduced in C# 7.  Alas, the only C#7 online compiler I could find runs .NET Core, which is super cumbersome for small examples, but rest assured it works exactly the same in a .NET Framework project.

---

### Original Answer

Microsoft doesn't (currently) have a simple format string shortcut for this.  The easiest options have already been shared.

#### C#

```cs
string.Format("{0}hr {1:mm}mn {1:ss}sec", (int)t.TotalHours, t);
```

#### VB

```vb
String.Format("{0}hr {1:mm}mn {1:ss}sec", _
              CInt(Math.Truncate(t.TotalHours)), _
              t)
```

However, an overly-thorough option is to implement your own `ICustomFormatter` for `TimeSpan`.  I wouldn't recommend it unless you use this so often that it would save you time in the long run.  However, there are times where you DO write a class where writing your own `ICustomFormatter` is appropriate, so I wrote this one as an example.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom string formatter for TimeSpan that allows easy retrieval of Total segments.
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// TimeSpan myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(27, 13, 5);
/// string.Format("{0:th,###}h {0:mm}m {0:ss}s", myTimeSpan) -> "27h 13m 05s"
/// string.Format("{0:TH}", myTimeSpan) -> "27.2180555555556"
/// 
/// NOTE: myTimeSpan.ToString("TH") does not work.  See Remarks.
/// </example>
/// <remarks>
/// Due to a quirk of .NET Framework (up through version 4.5.1), 
/// <code>TimeSpan.ToString(format, new TimeSpanFormatter())</code> will not work; it will always call 
/// TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized() which takes a DateTimeFormatInfo rather than an 
/// IFormatProvider/ICustomFormatter.  DateTimeFormatInfo, unfortunately, is a sealed class.
/// </remarks>
public class TimeSpanFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to create a wrapper format string with the specified format.
    /// </summary>
    private const string DefaultFormat = "{{0:{0}}}";

    /// <remarks>
    /// IFormatProvider.GetFormat implementation. 
    /// </remarks>
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        // Determine whether custom formatting object is requested. 
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
        {
            return this;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified format is looking for a total, and formats it accordingly.
    /// If not, returns the default format for the given <para>format</para> of a TimeSpan.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The formatted string for the given TimeSpan.
    /// </returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// ICustomFormatter.Format implementation.
    /// </remarks>
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // only apply our format if there is a format and if the argument is a TimeSpan
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(format) ||
            formatProvider != this || // this should always be true, but just in case...
            !(arg is TimeSpan) ||
            arg == null)
        {
            // return the default for whatever our format and argument are
            return GetDefault(format, arg);
        }

        TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)arg;

        string[] formatSegments = format.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2);
        string tsFormat = formatSegments[0];

        // Get inner formatting which will be applied to the int or double value of the requested total.
        // Default number format is just to return the number plainly.
        string numberFormat = "{0}";
        if (formatSegments.Length > 1)
        {
            numberFormat = string.Format(DefaultFormat, formatSegments[1]);
        }

        // We only handle two-character formats, and only when those characters' capitalization match
        // (e.g. 'TH' and 'th', but not 'tH').  Feel free to change this to suit your needs.
        if (tsFormat.Length != 2 ||
            char.IsUpper(tsFormat[0]) != char.IsUpper(tsFormat[1]))
        {
            return GetDefault(format, arg);
        }

        // get the specified time segment from the TimeSpan as a double
        double valAsDouble;
        switch (char.ToLower(tsFormat[1]))
        {
            case 'd':
                valAsDouble = span.TotalDays;
                break;
            case 'h':
                valAsDouble = span.TotalHours;
                break;
            case 'm':
                valAsDouble = span.TotalMinutes;
                break;
            case 's':
                valAsDouble = span.TotalSeconds;
                break;
            case 'f':
                valAsDouble = span.TotalMilliseconds;
                break;
            default:
                return GetDefault(format, arg);
        }

        // figure out if we want a double or an integer
        switch (tsFormat[0])
        {
            case 'T':
                // format Total as double
                return string.Format(numberFormat, valAsDouble);

            case 't':
                // format Total as int (rounded down)
                return string.Format(numberFormat, (int)valAsDouble);

            default:
                return GetDefault(format, arg);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the formatted value when we don't know what to do with their specified format.
    /// </summary>
    private string GetDefault(string format, object arg)
    {
        return string.Format(string.Format(DefaultFormat, format), arg);
    }
}
```

Note, as in the remarks in the code, `TimeSpan.ToString(format, myTimeSpanFormatter)` will not work due to a quirk of the .NET Framework, so you'll always have to use string.Format(format, myTimeSpanFormatter) to use this class.  See [How to create and use a custom IFormatProvider for DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382154/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-iformatprovider-for-datetime).

**EDIT**:
If you really, and I mean *really*, want this to work with `TimeSpan.ToString(string, TimeSpanFormatter)`, you can add the following to the above `TimeSpanFormatter` class:

```
/// <remarks>
/// Update this as needed.
/// </remarks>
internal static string[] GetRecognizedFormats()
{
    return new string[] { "td", "th", "tm", "ts", "tf", "TD", "TH", "TM", "TS", "TF" };
}
```

And add the following class somewhere in the same namespace:

```
public static class TimeSpanFormatterExtensions
{
    private static readonly string CustomFormatsRegex = string.Format(@"([^\\])?({0})(?:,{{([^(\\}})]+)}})?", string.Join("|", TimeSpanFormatter.GetRecognizedFormats()));

    public static string ToString(this TimeSpan timeSpan, string format, ICustomFormatter formatter)
    {
        if (formatter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        TimeSpanFormatter tsFormatter = (TimeSpanFormatter)formatter;

        format = Regex.Replace(format, CustomFormatsRegex, new MatchEvaluator(m => MatchReplacer(m, timeSpan, tsFormatter)));
        return timeSpan.ToString(format);
    }

    private static string MatchReplacer(Match m, TimeSpan timeSpan, TimeSpanFormatter formatter)
    {
        // the matched non-'\' char before the stuff we actually care about
        string firstChar = m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty;
        
        string input;
        if (m.Groups[3].Success)
        {
            // has additional formatting
            input = string.Format("{0},{1}", m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
        }
        else
        {
            input = m.Groups[2].Value;
        }

        string replacement = formatter.Format(input, timeSpan, formatter);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(replacement))
        {
            return firstChar;
        }

        return string.Format("{0}\\{1}", firstChar, string.Join("\\", replacement.ToCharArray()));
    }
}
```

After this, you may use

```
ICustomFormatter formatter = new TimeSpanFormatter();
string myStr = myTimeSpan.ToString(@"TH,{000.00}h\:tm\m\:ss\s", formatter);
```

where `{000.00}` is however you want the TotalHours int or double to be formatted.  Note the enclosing braces, which should not be there in the string.Format() case.  Also note, `formatter` *must be* declared (or cast) as `ICustomFormatter` rather than `TimeSpanFormatter`.

Excessive?  Yes.  Awesome?  Uhhh....

Comment: Your short and sweet answer takes into account leading zeros, beautiful! Was stuck with the likes of "47:33:4" for a while.. better than Skeet himself!

Comment: I really love this solution. Unfortunately it won't be usable in two way binding scenario, because there is no implementation of `TimeSpan.Parse` that would take an instance of `ICustomFormatter`.

Comment: @modiX Would you post an example of how you're using it?  I might be able to finagle a solution, and I want to start working with the correct context.  Between extension methods and [`DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, formatProvder)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx), there may be a solution.

Answer (score 4):

`string.Format("{0}hr {1}mn {2}sec", (int) t.TotalHours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);`

Comment: This is only for TimeSpan < 24 hr. And t,Seconds should be t.Seconds

Comment: You should change that to `{0:f0} ..., t.TotalHours, ...`

Comment: Still, you need to tweak (int) t.TotalHours, see my comment on Jon Skeet post about rounding.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1254234568);
Console.WriteLine($"{((int)ts.TotalHours).ToString("d2")}hr {ts.Minutes.ToString("d2")}mm {ts.Seconds.ToString("d2")}sec");
```

Comment: `toString("d2")` with connection with accepted answer gets the best result

Answer (score 2):

As per (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx), the default ToString() method for a TimeSpan object uses the "c" formatting, which means that by default, a timespan longer than 24 hours looks something like "1.03:14:56" when output to a razor view. This caused some confusion with my customers who do not understand that the "1." represents one day.

So, if you can use interpolated strings (C#6+), an easy way that I came up with to preserve the default formatting as much as possible, while using TotalHours instead of Days+Hours is to provide a get property to output the time as a formatted string in, like so:

```
public TimeSpan SystemTime { get; set; }
public string SystemTimeAsString
{
    get
    {
        // Note: ignoring fractional seconds.
        return $"{(int)SystemTime.TotalHours}:SystemTime.Minutes.ToString("00")}:SystemTime.Seconds.ToString("00")}";
    }
}
```

The result of this using the same time as above will be "27:14:56".

Answer (score 1):

You may need to calculate the hours.  The range for hours in TimeSpan.ToString is only 0-23.

The worst you'll need is to do raw string formatting a la Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Function:

```
Public Shared Function GetTimeSpanString(ByVal ts As TimeSpan) As String
        Dim output As New StringBuilder()

        Dim needsComma As Boolean = False

        If ts = Nothing Then

            Return "00:00:00"

        End If

        If ts.TotalHours >= 1 Then
            output.AppendFormat("{0} hr", Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours))
            If ts.TotalHours > 1 Then
                output.Append("s")
            End If
            needsComma = True
        End If

        If ts.Minutes > 0 Then
            If needsComma Then
                output.Append(", ")
            End If
            output.AppendFormat("{0} m", ts.Minutes)
            'If ts.Minutes > 1 Then
            '    output.Append("s")
            'End If
            needsComma = True
        End If

        Return output.ToString()

 End Function
```

[Convert A Timespan To Hours And Minutes](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=307122)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org)'s `Duration` type.

For example:

```
Duration d = Duration.FromSeconds(sec);
```

Or

```
Duration d = Duration.FromTimeSpan(ts);
```

You can then simply format it as a string, like this:

```
string result = d.ToString("H'hr' m'mn' s'sec'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [pattern-based API](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/text.html) instead:

```
DurationPattern p = DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("H'hr' m'mn' s'sec'");
string result = p.Format(d);
```

The advantage with the pattern API is that you only need to create the pattern once.  If you have a lot of values to parse or format, there can be a significant performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
string text = Math.Floor(timeUsed.TotalHours) + "h " + ((int)timeUsed.TotalMinutes) % 60 + "min";
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel has other format different to .NET.

Check this Link http://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt8

I create a simple function that convert a TimeSpan in a DateTime with the MS Excel format

```
    public static DateTime MyApproach(TimeSpan time)
    {
        return new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).Add(time).AddDays(-2);
    }
```

and you need to format the cell like this:

```
col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "[H]:mm:ss";
```