# format TimeSpan summary in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan, stimulsoft

I'm creating simple table report with column of TimeSpan type. 
I'm summing its values, which leads into values bigger than 24 hours, into Text componnent.

```
{SumTime(DataBand1,Records.time)}
```

I'm trying to format Text field like HH:mm:ss, but for 25 hours it gives me 01:00:00 (or 1.01:00:00 with general formatting) instead of 25:00:00 what is my goal.

Edit: The problem is not how to format timespan, but how to associate formatted value into Stimulsoft's Text component.

Comment: Possibly relevant (I'm unfamiliar with stimulsoft) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505230/format-timespan-greater-than-24-hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Hours` property has a maximum of 24h. You could format it yourself using `String.Format` and `TimeSpan.TotalHours`:

```
string text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",
                     (int) Records.time.TotalHours, // TotalHours is double
                     Records.time.Minutes,
                     Records.time.Seconds);
```

Comment: Yes, using this format gives good result, but i need to know, how to associate use this text variable to the text field in stimulsoft's Text component

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an old question, but I stumbled upon it looking for a solution myself.  Having done some digging, here's what I've come up with:

Assuming you already have a timespan variable (either setting it in the datasource, or having a variable set with DateDiff), you can format it with the following:

```
{string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", 
                (int) Variable1.TotalHours, 
                 Variable1.Minutes,
                 Variable1.Seconds)}
```

Lets say you have two different fields (named Date1 and Date2) that you need to get the difference of, and don't feel like putting it into a variable:

```
{string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", 
                (int) DateDiff(Date2,Date1).TotalHours, 
                 DateDiff(Date2,Date1).Minutes,
                 DateDiff(Date2,Date1).Seconds)}
```