# Need only HH:MM:SS in time span string

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a time span string as

```
1.21:00:00
```

it means 45 hours and i need it as

```
45:00:00
```

is it possible to do that in c#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505230/format-timespan-greater-than-24-hour

Comment: Could you please elaborate how it mean 45 hrs?

Comment: it means 1 day and 21 hours , 1 day have 24 hours so 24+21=45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding my answer because the string formatting can be done easier than current suggestions.

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("1.21:00:00");
string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", ts.TotalHours, ts); // 45:00:00
```

Unlike Jon's answer it doesn't require escaping. And unlike Soner's answer, it doesn't require passing the parameter twice.

Edit

---

For fractional TotalHours you probably want to floor the value like so:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("1.21:55:00");      
string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts);
```

Comment: i used you suggestion it works but when i  pass "1.21:20:00" this parameter then it gives "45.3333333333333:20:00" but i only need "45:20:00".

Comment: One issue more sir. Now this function return me 1 hour more than actual hours. kindly recheck please

Comment: @Waqas did you use Math.Floor? Because Round or Ceiling would cause it it to go up instead of down. Can you give me a test value that causes it to round up?

Comment: yeah i used it, code is running quite well but give me 1 hours greater than accurate duration

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't think the [`TimeSpan` custom formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) makes this feasible :(

You could either perform the string formatting yourself...

```
string text = (int) span.TotalHours + span.ToString(@"\:mm\:ss");
```

Or

```
string text = string.Format(@"{0}:{1:mm\:ss}", (int) span.TotalHours, span);
```

... or you could use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, which *does* allow for this:

```
// Or convert from a TimeSpan to a Duration
var duration = Duration.FromHours(50);
var durationPattern = DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("HH:mm:ss");
Console.WriteLine(durationPattern.Format(duration)); // 50:00:00
```

Obviously I'd recommend moving your whole code base over to Noda Time to make all your date/time code clearer, but I'm biased :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is string and your `CurrentCulture` has `:` as a `TimeSeparator`, you can use like;

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("1.21:00:00");
string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{2:ss}", ts.TotalHours, ts, ts); // 45:00:00
```

or you can combine minute and second parts as Jon did like;

```
string.Format(@"{0}:{1:mm\:ss}", ts.TotalHours, ts) // 45:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Span.TotalHours` property to get total hours from a time span.

```
TimeSpan span;
string timeSpan = "1.21:00:00";
TimeSpan.TryParse(timeSpan, out span);
double hours = span.TotalHours;
```

Comment: if i have this timespan(1,21,20,0) then it give me like 45.333333333333329 and i need 45:20:00.Can you please update it for me?