# Need to correct time span string format

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a time span string as

```
1.21:00:00
```

it means 45 hours and i need it as

```
45:00:00
```

and i use following method from
[Need only HH:MM:SS in time span string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309526/need-only-hhmmss-in-time-span-string)

it works perfectly for this above problem but when i change the string as

```
 1.21:30:00
```

then mentioned code return me one hour more than actual time. in this case it return me 46:29:00 but actual that i need is 45:29:00.

I am using c#

EDIT

```
public Tuple<string,string>  Calculate_Hours(DateTime strt, DateTime end)
{
    TimeSpan wrkhrs = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan exthrs=new TimeSpan(0,0,0);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from vw_Rept_Attend where UserID ='"+Convert.ToInt32 (cmbEmp.SelectedValue)+"' and convert(date,AtnDate) between '"+strt.Date+"' and '"+end.Date+"'",conn);
    conn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr["WorkHrs"].ToString().Length>0)
           wrkhrs=wrkhrs.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["WorkHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay);
       // exthrs = exthrs.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay);

        if (!dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Contains("-") && dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            exthrs = exthrs.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay);
        }
        else if (dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Contains("-") && dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            //int index = dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().LastIndexOf('-');
            //string rhs = dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Substring(index + 1);
            string ext = dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().Substring(dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString().LastIndexOf("-") +1);
            //TimeSpan test = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ExtraHrs"].ToString()).TimeOfDay.Negate();
            exthrs = exthrs.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(ext).TimeOfDay);
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
    dr.Close();
   // string tst = exthrs.ToString().Substring(exthrs.ToString().LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
   // wrkhrs.ToString();
   // exthrs.ToString();
    var val1 = TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString());
   string val3= string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", Math.Floor(TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString()).TotalHours), TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString()));
    var val2=TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString());
    string val4=string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", Math.Floor(TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString()).TotalHours), TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString()));
    return new Tuple<string, string>(string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", Math.Floor(TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString()).TotalHours), TimeSpan.Parse(wrkhrs.ToString())), string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}", Math.Floor(TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString()).TotalHours), TimeSpan.Parse(exthrs.ToString())));
   // MessageBox.Show(wrkhrs.ToString()+exthrs.ToString());
}
```

this is what i did yet.

Comment: What do you mean by _time span string_ exactly? You have a `TimeSpan` or `string`?

Comment: 1.21 equals 45 how come that ...is there any logic behind this

Comment: @PranayRana It means 1 day and 21 hour in a custom timespan string.

Comment: @PranayRana 1.21 equals 1 day and 21 hours

Comment: 1 day=24 hours and here 1.21 means 1 day and 21 hours so 24+21=45

Comment: How about you start the debugger and inspect some variables instead of copy-pasting your previous question with some additional text? This is what you get from copying code off the internet without understanding what it does, which has little to do with programming.

Comment: @SonerGönül it is time span

Comment: @CodeCaster at that time code was running good because string didn't contain mins section but after testing many inputs this issue came across.

Comment: That's nice and all, but your question is not good. Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Show the code, the input, the expected output and what you have tried to fix your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster,@Graffito see my edit i added my whole code here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need only HH:MM:SS in time span string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309526/need-only-hhmmss-in-time-span-string)

Comment: You add 30 minutes to the original timespan string but the expected result should be 29 minutes?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, this is just an example , i tested this with multiple inputs

Comment: Way too much code to clearify your question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i got it since your expected result is strange. You add 30 minutes but expect 29 minutes in the result string? If i ignore that this should work:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("1.21:30:00");
string result = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

Returns: `45:30:00`

You can use `Math.Abs` if you want to handle negative timespans:

```
String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (int)ts.TotalHours, Math.Abs(ts.Minutes), Math.Abs(ts.Seconds));
```

Comment: and what about if input time span is in negative form? i mean if time will be   "-1.21:30:00"

Comment: @Waqas: what is your expected result then? I have edited my answer, you can use `Math.Abs` to remove the minus sign on the minutes or seconds.

Comment: i checked it with negative sign it returns "-45:-29:00" i need only 1 negative sign at the beginning of string i-e "-45:29:00". can you please do it for me?

Comment: @Waqas: as mentioned, that is already handled by my second approach.

Comment: thanks, i add Math.abs to that. Now its fine, Thanks for you time.