# How to display Hours and Minutes from timespan with more than 24 hours

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

My timespan is for example:

```
Timespan span = new Timespan(40,24,34);
```

And I have this line

```
FormClock.Text = TimeToInstall.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

I want to display this in the Text like this:

40:24:34

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505230/format-timespan-greater-than-24-hour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx), you can't do it with a standard .ToString() format.
The [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a timespan seems to be what you need to get from days to hours.

From MSDN:

> TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
>         Console.WriteLine("Value of TimeSpan: {0}", interval);
>
> ```
>   Console.WriteLine("{0:N5} hours, as follows:", interval.TotalHours);
>   Console.WriteLine("   Hours:        {0,3}", 
>                     interval.Days * 24 + interval.Hours);
>   Console.WriteLine("   Minutes:      {0,3}", interval.Minutes);
>   Console.WriteLine("   Seconds:      {0,3}", interval.Seconds);
>   Console.WriteLine("   Milliseconds: {0,3}", interval.Milliseconds);
> ```

So in your case:

```
FormClock.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}". TimeToInstall.Days * 24 + TimeToInstall.Hours, TimeToInstall.Minutes, TimeToInstall.Seconds);
```

If it's something you're going to use a lot you could look at rolling it into some sort of extension method.

Comment: I couldn't believe it, so thanks for including the link ;-) In my case (mm:ss), I had to add another term for the whole minutes... Little dissapointing for a TimeSpan class :-)

Comment: this is the smartest solution i have across so far