# Convert this String to hours and minutes c#

Tags: c#, regex

Input value is only like this in string value and nothing else:   `P0DT3H40M0S` 
This indicates travel time and needs to be converted to hours and minutes.
D signifies Day, T is Time (right part signifies Time, above sample was:  3 Hours And 40 Minutes and 0 Seconds. H-hours, M-Minutes, S-Seconds)
If there's a value in D, eg.  `P1DT3H40M0S`  - this already signifies 1 Day and 3 Hours and 40 minutes and 0 Seconds, so output should be 27 Hours and 40 minutes. How do i get the values for Days, Hours and minutes using Regex? or can i use substring? my problem is if there were 2 digit Days and Hours, substring won't work.   i need to get the numbers leftside the D, H and M.

Comment: You could use Noda Time, which will parse that into a `Period` object very easily... you'd then normalize it yourself.

Comment: @alomegah you don't need a regex, you can use TimeSpan.ParseExact. The resulting object will have a day portion but that doesn't matter in calculations. You can use custom formatting to display the timespan as total hours + minutes instead of days, hours etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [TimeSpan.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse this string into a TimeSpan

```
var pattern=@"\Pd\D\Th\Hm\Ms\S";
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("P01DT3H40M0S",pattern,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can use the TimeSpan object in calculations. It supports addition, subtraction and comparison.

You can extract the total duration in hours using [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx). In this case, this will return `27.6666666`. You can get the whole hours just by casting to int, `(int)ts.TotalHours` will return `27`.

[Copying from one of Jon Skeet's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505230/format-timespan-greater-than-24-hour) you can format the string as hours/minutes by using the truncated TotalHours and the Minutes, Seconds component:

```
String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",(int)ts.TotalHours,ts.Minutes,ts.Seconds)
```

This will return `27:40:0`

Comment: This works, with the conversion as well.