# How to calculate Total Hours from Time in Hours:Minutes in RDLC Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am using RDLC Report. My requirement is, I need to calculate total Hours from values like

```
           Wrking Hour
             9:45 
             10:02

             11:00
Total Hours: 30:47
```

Main thing it is including blank values. So How I need to make equation for RDLC Report for getting total hours:minutes.

I tried running the below code, but it shows error:

```
System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(sum(Fields!TimeDiff.Value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works without an error but it would yield `1.06:47` which isn't your desired format. Unfortunately .NET doesn't have a format string for more than 24 hours (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3505245/3959259)).

You can get your desired result if you do the formatting yourself and show your result as a string:

```
=CStr(Math.Truncate(System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TimeDiff.Value)).TotalHours)) +
 ":" + CStr(System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!TimeDiff.Value)).Minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

=System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sum(Fields!TimeDiff.Value)).Hours