# Conversion of string into timespan with Sum

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

Hi I have to execute a sum of hours, to do so I use the code c # below: first convert hourtot into timespan then I execute the total sum, at the end the total I get 08:30 which is impossible, how can I solve this? and what is it due to?

**C# Code:**

```
    /*
    hourtot values:
    08:30
    10:00
    09:00
    08:30
    10:00
    10:30*/

TimeSpan tot= TimeSpan.Zero;
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
    String hourtot= r.CaricaOreGiornaliere(dr["date"].ToString());
    if(hourtot.Equals("00:00") == false)
    {
      TimeSpan hourcant= TimeSpan.Parse(hourtot.ToString());
      tot= tot+ hourcant;
    }
    }
   labelris.text = "" + tot.ToString(@"hh\:mm"); //this print 08:30
```

Comment: yes i'm sure...

Comment: What does `tot.ToString()` print out?

Comment: If you wanted the answer in days, hours and minutes you could use: `tot.ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm")`

Comment: ToString(@"hh\:mm"); is truncating hours > 24 hours.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505230/format-timespan-greater-than-24-hour

Comment: Try `string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int)tot.TotalHours, tot.Minutes)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `tot.ToString(@"hh\:mm");` line.

When you use `hh` and `mm`, it uses `Hours` and `Minutes` values of your `TimeSpan` object, not `TotalHours` and `TotalMinutes` which is what you want.

So, if your total is more than one day in terms of hours, it will take the first 24 hours as a day. For example, if your total is 27 hours, then your `TimeSpan.Days` will be `1`, and `TimeSpan.Hours` will be `3`.

Here's the exact same program of yours but written as a simple Console program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> times = new List<string>();
    times.Add("08:30");
    times.Add("10:00");
    times.Add("09:00");

    TimeSpan tot = TimeSpan.Zero;
    foreach (var time in times)
    {
        if (time.Equals("00:00") == false)
        {
            TimeSpan hourcant = TimeSpan.Parse(time);
            tot = tot + hourcant;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(tot.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the output is

> 03:30

However, looks at the values of `tot` inside the debugger.

[image]

So your method is fine you need to print it better.
Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total Hours = {0}", tot.TotalHours);
```

### EDIT:

Using Matthew Watson's suggestion below will give the output in the exact format you want.

```
Console.WriteLine(tot.ToString(@"d\.hh\:mm"));
```