# Custom number group (thousand separator) for 1000,000 format in c#

Tags: c#

My code is as below I am trying to get custom grouping on number 
example: 1000000 should be 1000,000

I have tried many search result that allows thousand separator and also custom grouping but each one gives a result like 10,00,000

```
decimal value = decimal.Parse(txtamount.Text.Trim());
txtamount.Text = value.ToString("#,###0");
```

In this code I have tried below code also

```
txtamount.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", value);
txtamount.Text = value.ToString("#,##0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
txtamount.Text = value.ToString("0,0.0",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //-->1,000,000.0
```

It is not a normal thousand separator grouping of a number.
I am trying to get output in a format 1000,000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Comment: Thank you for reference i have tried i but it is not giving desire result in format 1000,000

Comment: So you want thousand separator for the first thousand and not for the rest of the number? What could be the use case here?

Comment: How do you want to format 2 million? 10 million?

Answer (score 2):

To just have one grouping separator, you can use this:

```
// create a writable copy of the culture of your choice
var ci = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us").Clone();

// change the group sizes: the first one after 3 digits (counting backwards)
// NO second (third, ..) one!
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new[]{3,0};

// and use it 
// the , in the format means "use a group separator", it does NOT specify a position
var millionString1 = 1_000_000.ToString("#,#", ci); // 1000,000
var millionString2 = 1_000_000.ToString("N0", ci); // also 1000,000
```

But do note that 10 million would now become 10000,000.

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a custom format, you'll need to escape your comma `,`

```
string.Format("{0:####\\,###}",value)
```

Comment: seems to result in `,10` for numbers less than 1000

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem possible without a [custom formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577011/custom-string-formatter-in-c-sharp), but the comma can be inserted after. For example :

```
string value = "1234567.890"
string result = Regex.Replace(value, @"(\d+)(\d\d\d)", "$1,$2");  // result = "1234,567.890"
```