# How does C# recognize the 0 and 1 in these lines of code as num 1 and num2?

Tags: c#

My instructions were to write a C# program to print on screen the output of adding, subtracting, multiplying and dividing of two numbers which will be entered by the user.

The lines of code below seemed to be the simplest way to input values and print them out. Is `{0} + {1} = {2}` an expression innately built into C#? I'm not sure how num1 and num2 are being picked up as 0 and 1 in this instance and the answer as 2.

```cs
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
int num1= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
int num2= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1+num2);
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1-num2);
Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1*num2);
Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1/num2);
Console.WriteLine("{0} mod {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1%num2);
//10 + 2 = 12                                                                                                   
//10 - 2 = 8                                                                                                    
//10 x 2 = 20                                                                                                   
//10 / 2 = 5                                                                                                    
//10 mod 2 = 0
```

Comment: Built in to the BCL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types?view=netframework-4.8#composite-formatting

Comment: well, for starters, have you read the documentation? it is very comprehensive... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This `"{0} + {1} = {2}` is formatted message, so `{0}` refers to first index which is `num1` in your code..

Comment: Related question: [String.Format - how it works and how to implement custom formatstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512349/string-format-how-it-works-and-how-to-implement-custom-formatstrings)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `{0} + {1} = {2}` in this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1+num2);
```

**Does not mean** `0 + 1 = 2`. The `{0}` means the first argument after the comma (which is `num1`). In general, `{x}` where `x` is an integer greater than or equal to 0, means the `x` argument after the comma, where the first argument is `{0}`, the second one is `{1}` and so on. This is due to C# having *zero based indexing*, which basically means that the index (or position) of an item in a collection (or set) starts at `0` for the first item, `1` for the second and so on...

The string `"{0} + {1} = {2}"` is a *formatted string*, where the `{x}` is substituted by the `x` argument after the coma. Therefore, in the earlier line of code, if `num1 = 7` and `num2 = 4`, then it would print:
`7 + 4 = 11`, because `{0} = num1 = 7`, `{1} = num2 = 4` and `{2} = num1 + num2 = 7 + 4 = 11`.

The same goes for the other `Console.WriteLine` lines of your code.

Here's another example:

```
Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
string name= Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter your last name: ");
string lastName= Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
int age = Convert.Int32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0} {1} and your age is {2}", name, lastName, age);
```

Here, `{0} = name`, `{1} = lastName` and `{2} = age`.

Comment: `{0}` refers to index

Comment: @Saif of course it does. But thought that dumping the line *zero based indexing* to the OP might seem complicated to him/her.

Comment: @Saif edited, tried to explain it plain and simple.

Comment: `{}` represents placeholder and `0` represents the value in index `0`

Answer (score 0):

## Console.WriteLine is a method that takes parameters

`Console.WriteLine` is 'just' a method that takes parameters, which are evaluated when the method is called.

Please consider the following example.

```
static void PrintSum(int num1, int num2, int result) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, result);
}

PrintSum(num1, num2, num1+num2);
// 10 + 2 = 12
```

### `params object[]`

In fact, [`WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) can accept `params object[]` and when `WriteLine` is called the arguments are already evaluated. I hope the snippets below helps to showcase what's happening.

### Snippet 1

```
static void WriteLineWrapper(string template, params object[] objects) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i< objects.Length; i++ )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {objects[i]}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(template, objects);
}

(...)

WriteLineWrapper("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1+num2);
```

Output

```
0: 10
1: 2
2: 12
10 + 2 = 12
```

### Snippet 2

```
static void Print(params object[] toPrint) {
    // Note the change of order 0,2,1,3, not 0,1,2,3
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {2} {1} = {3}", toPrint[0], toPrint[1], toPrint[2], toPrint[3]);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num1 = 10;
    int num2 = 2;
    Print(num1, num2, "+", num1+num2);
    Print(num1, num2, "-", num1-num2);
    Print(num1, num2, "*", num1*num2);
    Print(num1, num2, "/", num1/num2);
    Print(num1, num2, "mod", num1%num2);

    Print(num1, num2, "+"); // Oops
}
```

Output

```
10 + 2 = 12
10 - 2 = 8
10 * 2 = 20
10 / 2 = 5
10 mod 2 = 0
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

## String interpolation

BTW. You could use [$ - string interpolation (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

```
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} + {num2} = {num1+num2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} - {num2} = {num1-num2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} x {num2} = {num1*num2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} / {num2} = {num1/num2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{num1} mod {num2} = {num1%num2}");
```