# How can a string timestamp with hours 0 to 24 be parsed

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to parse a string timestamp of format `"yyyyMMddHHmmss"` with `DateTime.ParseExact()`. The catch is I must allow for an hour value of "24" (i.e. hours can be from 0 to 24, where **hour 24 denotes hour 0 of the next day** (day + 1, hour = 0) Note: I can't control the input values.) and, of course, that results in an exception.
Are there any settings/properties I can set instead of manually parsing/using regex's? If not, any efficient parsing ideas?
ex.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20120911240000", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", 
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What does hour 24 mean?  Hour 0 is midnight, so is hour 24 the following day at midnight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse C# string to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580809/parse-c-sharp-string-to-datetime)

Comment: @HenkHolterman  I hate it when people say "possible duplicate" before actually reading the question

Comment: added example, and corrected date/time format string

Comment: hour 24 means hour 0 of next day (so day + 1, hour = 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam's solution is good, but since you are using `yyyyMMddHHmmss` I would do something like:

```
bool addDay = false;
DateTime result;
string dtToParse = "20120911240000";

if (dtToParse[8] == '2' && dtToParse[9] == '4')
{
    dtToParse = dtToParse.Substring(0, 8) + "00" + dtToParse.Substring(10);
    addDay = true;
}

result = DateTime.ParseExact(dtToParse, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (addDay) { result = result.AddDays(1); }
```

Comment: @user897052 I added in your fixes.  I did not actually test it, hence the simple problems.  If this solved your issue please mark it as the answer.

Comment: no worries, a good example any way; thanks<br /> @Sam I am and Trisped: I used similar code, temporarily, as a solution. My next goal is to use something a bit more robust/dynamic, perhaps utilizing a custom IFormatProvider as Victor Ronin suggested.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to do it manually you can use [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) to detect hour values of "24", then use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace), to set that to "00", then parse your date, and then add a day if that's what an hours value of "24" means

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but targeting the hours seemed to make it a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple flag to do what you want.

However, here is the way to create custom datetime parser:

[How to create and use a custom IFormatProvider for DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382154/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-iformatprovider-for-datetime)