# Trying to implement a custom formatter but ICustomFormatter.Format is never called

Tags: c#, iformatprovider

I'm trying to figure out how IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter work after following [Format TimeSpan in DataGridView column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627922/format-timespan-in-datagridview-column) on how to customize a TimeSpan in a DataGridView. I've created a completely custom formatter that always returns "foo" regardless of what it is formatting.

I'm using it on Int but I assume it should work on all types as it doesn't check the value being passed, it just returns `"foo"`.

```
class MyFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetFormat");
        return this;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Format");
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

And I'm passing it to `int.ToString()`:

```
int number = 10;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString(new MyFormatter()));
```

What I'm getting is:

```
GetFormat
10
```

While what I was hoping to get is:

```
GetFormat
Format
foo
```

**Edit:** I found [How to create and use a custom IFormatProvider for DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382154/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-iformatprovider-for-datetime?rq=1) and the answers there say that `DateTime.ToString()` will not accept anything but `DateTimeFormatInfo` or `CultureInfo` and an object will be rejected if it's not of these types even if it implements `ICustomFormatter` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382481/492336.

So my question is then does that hold in all cases of the `ToString()` methods? Does it hold also for DataGridView, and in which cases can I pass a truly custom formatter?

Comment: I doubt it helps but `Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new MyFormatter(), "{0}", number));` creates the correct output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call ToString on integer and provide IFormatProvider, it will try to extract **NumberFormatInfo** from it, roughly in the following way:

```
public static NumberFormatInfo GetInstance(IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
  CultureInfo cultureInfo = formatProvider as CultureInfo;
  if (cultureInfo != null && !cultureInfo.m_isInherited)
    return cultureInfo.numInfo ?? cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
  NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = formatProvider as NumberFormatInfo;
  if (numberFormatInfo != null)
    return numberFormatInfo;
  if (formatProvider != null)
  {
    NumberFormatInfo format = formatProvider.GetFormat(typeof (NumberFormatInfo)) as NumberFormatInfo;
    if (format != null)
      return format;
  }
  return NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
}
```

So you see if all else fails, it calls `GetFormat` with type equal to `NumberFormatInfo`, and expects `NumberFormatInfo` back. You don't return it from `GetFormat`, so it uses default formatter instead (current cutlure). So valid way to use it in this case would be something like:

```
class MyFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(NumberFormatInfo)) {
            return new NumberFormatInfo()
            {
                // something here
            };
        }
        Console.WriteLine("GetFormat");
        return this;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Format");
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

But this way I doubt you can return arbitrary values like "foo" for any number.

Comment: Sure, because it cannot be done by providing IFormatProvider to number.ToString. You can only return NumberFormatInfo which doesn't support providing arbitrary values. So OP has to use different way to achieve his goal (and this goal is not very clear by the way).

Answer (score -2):

Actually ToString() function accept IFormatProvider as an argument its signature says:

```
ToString(IFormatProvider)
ToString(String)
ToString(String,IFormatProvider)
```

and IFormatProvider only has `GetFormat(Type)` function to implement. `ToString()` doesnt use `ICustomFormatter` which is having `Format()` function. So
the implementation for `IFormatProvider` is :

```
class MyFormatter : IFormatProvider
    {
        public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetFormat");
            return this;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Not every type that has a `ToString` overload with `IFormatProvider` actually seemingly uses `IFormatProvider` correctly, though.